# IP and network config

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have a question regarding IP and network config.

I have Ubuntu OS with KVM - Virt Manager and I installed two VM Guest OS(Ubuntu).I config the Host IP with 172.X.X.1(local IP) and try to access the two internal VM image with 172 .X.X. 2 and 172 .X.X. 3) with bridge connection but i cant able to access the two internal VM via external system.I tried but not giving successful result.

Its any thing i missed in the bridge configuration or any thing in internal VM image.

How to config this bridge connection and internal VM image?

172.x.x.1 ------ HOST - Ubuntu
|---- VM image 1 ---- > Ubuntu ---> 172.X.X.2
|---- VM Image 2 ---- > Ubunut ---> 172.X.X.3 ( I cant access the VM image via SSH and even in browser too)

But the Host System is works fine in most of the system - accessible via SSH and browser.

Comment: could you provide output of `ip link` , `ebtables -L` and `iptables -L -nv`. Im almost certain that its because of macvtap devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled packaet forwarding? If not follow the instructions [here](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch03_:_Linux_Networking#Configuring_IP_Forwarding)